# How to get JobStatus with Parse Server

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to know if it's possible to query the status of a specific job (or even all the jobs) in Cloud Code.

The only thing I found in the doc is this :

> Viewing jobs is supported on parse-dashboard starting version 1.0.19, but you can also query the _JobStatus class with a masterKey call to fetch your recent jobs

So I tried :

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: MASTER_KEY" \
https://myparsepath/parse/classes/JobStatus
```

But it returned this (which is not a list of my Jobs) :

```
{
  "objectId": "wRqETEgJc0",
  "createdAt": "2018-08-01T09:28:38.095Z"
}
```

That's why I ask for your help here.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you posted just created a JobStatus object which is different from the internal class _JobStatus that is used to track jobs.

try:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: MASTER_KEY" \
https://myparsepath/parse/classes/_JobStatus
```